# UCMA programming without lync server

Tags: lync-2010, ucma

I want to learn about UCMA 3.0 for my project. Can someone plc give some starting point to learn. In my case,i don't want to use lync server as my end point. In msdn i couldn't find such kind resource.
Thanks.

Comment: Found [this book](http://www.amazon.com/Professional-Communications-Development-Microsoft-Programmer/dp/0470939036) to be a great asset.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to build a UCMA endpoint to e.g. an IP-PBX - if so, [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg448007.aspx) discusses it, so it should be possible. I haven't come across any articles describing how to do this, but you should (in theory, anyway) be able to work through the [UCMA SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg421023.aspx) and get some of the samples working against your platform of choice.